# Vue instance not recognized in blade file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm so stumped by this rather *simple* vuejs problem.

Why does doing console.log(app2); work if I have this in my blade file (test_vodal.blade.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const app2 = new Vue({
    el: '#app2',

    data: {
        f: false,
        g: false
    }
});
console.log(app2);
</script>
@endsection
```

but give me an error if I move my code into app.js and have this?

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log(app2);
</script>
@endsection
```

With the latter I am seeing:

```
testVodal : 65 Uncaught ReferenceError: app2 is not defined
   at testVodal:65
```

Comment: app2 either isn't declared yet, or is in the wrong scope. try using window.app2 where you set it. This is not a permament solution though, it's not a very good practice to set global vars on the window.

Comment: agreed. this is not a very elegant solution. Using window.app2 works, though.
```window.app2 = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

```

From the blade file: 
```console.log(app2);
```

So what is the right way of doing this?

Comment: but did it fix it?

Comment: this is actually a vanilla js prob...

Comment: Yes it fixed it, but what is the problem in my vanilla js?

Comment: not sure... but it has something to do with scope. try changing const to var maybe.

Comment: Changing const to var does not work. ```testVodal:64 Uncaught ReferenceError: app2 is not defined
    at testVodal:64```

Comment: my guess is that it's a laravel thing... i tried it in a vanilla html thing and it worked fine
if you really need it fixed then youll just have to use window for now...

Comment: So here's what I found. webpack is changing the scope. Look for app2 in the snippet of my compiled app.js here: https://gist.github.com/connecteev/2013d78c25c7dcba266ec13dafe649ca

Comment: How do I fix this webpack config?

Comment: I don't know much about webpack, so I don't know. you can read docs here though: http://webpack.js.org